# Cisco Packet Tracer on elementary OS

Tags: applications

I have installed Cisco Packet Tracer 7.1 in my elementary OS, but when I want to launch it only says:

```
Starting Packet Tracer 7.1
```

...and the program didn't launch. For Ubuntu there are many possible solutions but none works.

Any idea?

Comment: I am having this same problem on linux mint 18.2 this is not an elementary problem ... afaict i'll post back if i find a solution did you give up and use wine? ... i'm about to

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to /opt/pt/bin and run PacketTracer7 manually it will give you a better idea of what is going on. I had to install some missing dependencies that weren't installed by the install script. This is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5 libqt5xml5 libqt5multimedia5
```

I am running Elementary OS Loki with the 64bit version of Packet Tracer 7.1

Also I have not been able to get it to run using: /opt/pt/packettracer however it's been running great using /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7

Also instead of using the Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop I used the Main Menu application to create the shortcut in my applications bin.

Here is the config I used for that:

[image: Launcher Properties]